# Django - How to check if model instance has unique one-to-many and many-to-many relations

Tags: python, django, django-models

## Question

I have five models:

```
class Features(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)


class Filter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)


class Model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)


class TrainSet(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(unique=True)


class Algorithm(models.Model):
    feature = models.ManyToManyField(Features)
    filter = models.ManyToManyField(Filter)
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    train_set = models.ForeignKey(TrainSet, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
```

I am doing some measurements that produce a calculated prediction based on `features`, `filters`, `model` and `trainset`. Those together form an `algorithm`
First four are being changed trough the development process and because of that I would like to save each measurement with `algorithm` version.

## Problem

If I would not care for data redundancy and database table normalizations I could create a different yet same algorithm for measurements. But because i care for redundancy and normalization I would like to check if the algorithm with respective one-to-many and many-to-many already exists. If instance exists, use that instance, otherwise create a new one.

after each measurement the server that calculates the result sends a JSON to my django server in following form:

```
{
    "filters": ["filter1", "filter2"],
    "model": "model-1",
    "features":["feature1", "feature2"],
    "trainset": "trainset1"
}
```

The problem is that i cannot find a way to check if an `algorithm` already exists with all its relations.
**What is the simplest way to find out if `algorithm` already exists?**

## Update 1

I have tried Mohammad Ali's answer and it works partially.
When the algorithm table is empty and i use following data:

```
{
    "filters": ["filter1", "filter2"],
    "model": "model-1",
    "features":["feature1", "feature2"],
    "trainset": "trainset1"
}
```

it obviously finds zero rows.
I then update the tables with data and then make the same query. It will then find the row with upper data.

But then I make a new request with the following data (filters and features are different than before).

```
{
    "filters": ["filter1", "filter3"],
    "model": "model-1",
    "features":["feature1", "feature3"],
    "trainset": "trainset1"
}
```

I get the same algorithm as before. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, with filter on Algorithm model, for example:

```
algorithmList = Algorithm.objects.filter(feature__name__in=['f1', 'f2'], filter__name__in=['fil1', 'fil2'], model__name__in=['m1', 'm2'], train_set__name__in=['t1', 't2'])

if algorithmList.count() == 0:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You add conditions by using filter multiple times. You can loop in to all your filters and features and add it to your query

```
query = Algorithm.objects.filter(train_set=train_set_obj, model=model_obj)
features = [feature_obj1,feature_obj2]
filters = [filter_obj1,filter_obj2]
for feature in features:
    query = query.filter(feature=feature)
for filter in filters:
    query = query.filter(filter=filter)
```

So, if query exists, that means Algorithm exist or else create a new one

Comment: This does not work if I have an algorithm with lets say one algorithm. One has three filters ['a','b','c'] and when i try to check if second algorithm exists with filters ['a', 'b'], it will give me first algorithm which is incorrect.

Comment: I didn't get you. Did you mean to say that if there are two algorithm with filter ['a','b','c'] and another with filter ['a','b'] and you query filter ['a','b'], both the algorithm should come?

Comment: If that's the case, you can try using Q() operator for more complex query. Possible usage would be to generate a OR query. Try this query,
`filter_query = None
for filter in filters:
    filter_query = filter_query | Q(filter=filter
query = query.filter(filter_query)
`
You can import Q operator from here
`from django.db.models import Q`